# Why do we use ^ operator when overriding GetHashCode method?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I was watching a video where we override `GetHashCode` method like this:

```
public override GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Name.GetHashCode() ^ this.Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

Why did we do that here to get the new `HashCode`? so why `XOR` operator between those two variables?

Here is the video:

https://youtu.be/XIbBfmsVzpg?list=PL6n9fhu94yhWi8K02Eqxp3Xyh_OmQ0Rp6

Time 9:55

Comment: @Abion47 Except it introduces an undue risk for potential collisions in many contexts, it's just easier to type that methods that actually do it more effectively.

Comment: Related: [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/263400/11683)